# Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, compute the stochastic integral $\int_0^t s W_s^2dW_s$. Why should I use $f(t,x)=tx^3/3$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, compute the stochastic integral $\int_0^t s W_s^2dW_s$.

I think I need to use itô's formula. In the answeres it says that the function I should take is: $f(t,x)=t\frac{x^3}{3}$. However I don't know why i should take that formula. It would really help if I knew why that formula is used. The book gives as final answere that the integral is equal to:

$\frac{t}{3}W_t^3 -\int_0^t \frac{W_s^3}{3} +sW_s \ \ ds$

I do get kind of close to this answer I think since I got stuck at

$\int_0^t \frac{W_s^3}{3}ds+\int_0^tsW_s^2dW_s +0.5\int_0^t 2sW_sd[W]_s = \frac{t}{3}W_s^3 +\int_0^t \frac{W_s^3}{3}ds +\int_0^tsW_sd[W]_s$

However I have difficulties with using the d[W]_s part. I tried
$\int_0^tsW_sd[W]_s =\int_0^tsW_sf(t,x)ds$ but this doesn't seem to get me the correct answer.

Comment: Check for typos in the solution given

Comment: There is no typo in the given solution, if the given solution is wrong the book is probably wrong. Did you get an other answere? Also do you know why this function $f(t,x)=t/3x^3$ is used?

Comment: I meant typos in this:
$$\frac{t}{3}W_t^3 -\int_0^t \frac{W_s^3}{3} +sW_s \ \ ds$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the differential
$$d(tW_t^3)=W_t^3dt+td(W_t^3)$$
With Ito we find $dF:=d(W_t^3)$. The derivatives are
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=0, \ \ \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial w}=3w^2, \ \ \ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial w^2}=6w$$
So
$$dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}dW_t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial w^2}dt=3W_t^2dW_t+3W_tdt$$
By plugging it in the first one:
$$d(tW_t^3)=W_t^3dt+3tW_t^2dW_t+3tW_tdt$$
Finally
$$3\int_0^tsW_s^2dW_s=tW_t^3-\int_0^tW_s^3ds-3\int_o^t sW_sds$$
$$\int_0^tsW_s^2dW_s=\frac{t}{3}W_t^3-\int_0^t\frac{W_s^3}{3}ds-\int_0^t sW_sds$$

---

Consider $F:=tW_t^3/3$. By Ito, we find the derivatives
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\frac{w^3}{3}, \ \ \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial w}=tw^2, \ \ \ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial w^2}=2tw$$
So
$$dF=d\bigg(\frac{t}{3}W_t^3\bigg)=\frac{W_t^3}{3}dt+tW_t^2dW_t+tW_tdt$$
And again
$$\int_0^tsW_s^2dW_s=\frac{t}{3}W_t^3-\int_0^t\frac{W_s^3}{3}ds-\int_0^tsW_sds$$

Comment: Thanks this is really helpfull! However I still don't completly understand why the function is chosen like that. Is it because the derivative of the function w.r.t. $W_t$ wil give $tW_t^2$?

Comment: @101010 write $w$ as the argument of the function under which we take derivatives. Yes the aim is to come up with our original function under the integral.

Comment: okay I think I understand, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @101010 you're welcome, leave an upvote when you can